# Meteor Handlebars: #if this equals - load different templates with helperfunction

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I'm quite new to Meteor and just trying to build my first meteor App also using [Transitioner](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-transitioner).

So what I'm trying to do is load different templates when a string passed to another template is equal to something.
The HTML code:

```
<template name="onePage">
  {{#if itIs "teams"}}
    {{> teams}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if itIs "players"}}
    {{> players}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
<template name="teams">
  <h2>These are the TEAMS</h2>
</template>
<template name="players">
  <h2>These are the PLAYERS</h2>
</template>
```

The JS code:

```
Template.onePage.itIs = function(passed) {
  return this === passed;
};
```

This does not work for some reason and I just don't understand why.
The only point really is that "this" passed to the onePage template is some string (coming from the URL). And if this string is "teams" I want to load the teams template, if it is "players" I want to load the players template.

As easy as that! :-)

Unfortunately I just can't solve this simple problem.

Hope you guys understand my problem and you can help!

best regards
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

What is `this` in the `Template.onePage.itIs` callback?

If you change that to a Session (which you set from a URL for example, maybe using the [Meteor Router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router)), then the code will probably work just fine!

So, for example, the /teams URL would set a [session](http://docs.meteor.com/#session) named showThisPage to 'teams', and the /players URL would set the showThisPage session to 'players', and the `Template.onePage.itIs` would check the passed value against this session insetead.

Something like this (I'm just typing this straight into stack overflow without testing it, but it should work):

```
Meteor.Router.add({ 
   '/teams': function() { Session.set('showThisPage', 'teams'); }, 
   '/players': function() { Session.set('showThisPage', 'players'); } 
});

Template.onePage.itIs = function(passed) {
  return Session.get('showThisPage') === passed;
};
```

Not tested like I said, but it should point you in the right direction.

(And instead of using the session you could just use Meteor.Router.page(), but you can read all about that on the [Meteor Router page](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router).)